# Error 400 - redirect_uri_mismatch in Google Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, google, console

I'm new to google console and encountering an issue while trying to access my app on Google Console, and the error message I'm encountering is:

**Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch**

I have already added specific URLs to "Authorized JavaScript Origins" and "Authorized Redirect URIs" in line with our AWS Cognito settings for "Allowed Callback URLs" and "Allowed Sign-out URLs."

As app developer, I'm uncertain about the correct URI configuration to resolve this issue. Could anyone provide guidance or point me to resources that can help me to configure the redirect URI correctly?

Your timely assistance is highly appreciated.

Thank you, Pragyan

Answer (score 0):

The `Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch` occurs when the redirect URI in your request does not match the Authorized Redirect URIs in the Google API Console. Here's how to troubleshoot it:

1. **Check Redirect URI in Application**: Verify that the redirect URI in your app matches exactly with one listed in the Google API Console.
2. **Exact Match for URIs**: URIs must match exactly, including the use of http vs https, and the presence or absence of trailing slashes.
3. **Multiple Environments**: If you use multiple environments, add each environment's redirect URI to the Google API Console.
4. **Update Google API Console**:

   - Visit the [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/).
   - Select your project.
   - Click "Credentials" in the sidebar.
   - Edit the client ID for your app.
   - Under "Authorized redirect URIs", ensure your AWS Cognito "Allowed Callback URLs" and "Allowed Sign-out URLs" are added.
5. **Consistency Across Platforms**: Ensure redirect URIs are consistent across all platforms (AWS Cognito and Google API Console).
6. **Propagation Time**: Changes in the Google API Console may take a few minutes to take effect.
7. **Correct Client ID**: Use the correct Client ID in your application that corresponds with the Google API Console.

Review the Google documentation for [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) and [OAuth 2.0 web server applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server) for detailed guidance.

Redirect URIs are crucial for the security of OAuth flows and must be configured accurately.